# Implementing PET thinking (designing for Persuation, Emotion, Trust) into agency process

Tags: website-design, design-process, emotion, trust

So I have been given the task of implementing in the [PET design techniques](http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2009/01/beyond-usability-designing-web-sites-for-persuasion-emotion-and-trust.php) into our agency's UX process and making sure this is instinctively baked into every project we do going forward.

Currently we use PET techniques but our whole approach is very ad hoc and it's hit or miss whether this occurs in a project or not.

So my question is this: What's the best way to implement this into the lifecycle of a project to make sure the whole team understands the rational behind our designs? How are you guys currently tackling this and how do I make this stick with a studio of around 70 people?

Advice and ideas would be a great starting point for me. Thanks for any input!

Comment: From what I can tell there are templates to help you implement the PET design techniques. What is the issue you are having with the whole approach being very ad hoc? Is it the people, the process or the governance that you are having issues with?

Comment: I think PET is basically *snake oil*, all their *discoveries* were made before I was born and we learmed that in college decades ago. Add some UX lingo and bam! This being said, these kind of approaches with designers is really hard: they have it or they don't. And if they don't, they usually won't care at all, because they'll usually tell you "duh, I know that since I was born!". So your best bet is to have a rigurous PM handling the project and "leading the herd", then designers will follow. Just a humble opinion nased on experience, not an answer

Comment: I looked at the linked article. For example, it says: "*Instead of designing only for what visitors* can do *on a site, superior Web design is now responsible for determining what customers* will do". I have never understood advertising, so I might be missing something. When I want something, I look for it, go to the place it is and acquire it. No one persuades me. I ignore advertising or even find that it turns me *away*. The things that really interest me are not advertised anyhow (amateur radio equipment, for example). Usually when I find a favorite product, it vanishes from lack of demand.

Comment: wow, 2 years later this question keeps getting bumped

Answer (score 1):

If you need to prove your Interface to your peers, the best way to do so is to conduct frequent **User Interviews** and record what the User feels with a drastic change.

Significant changes such as placement of UI elements, animations, color choices, all contribute towards achieving Persuasion, Emotion and Trust into the User.

Conducting Validation in every major design upgrade and interviews to know the psychology behind the changes occurred will help you achieve the correct and accurate design in the end and also have proof of concept for the entire team to know.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are following a process why not make the process into easy to follow templates.

Write down the PET techniques and print them out. The team should have them pinned up. This will at least provide visual guidelines for your coworkers. You could even put little check marks next to the guidelines to make it even more visual that your UX is following them.